# X and I not showing up well in medieval font

Tags: fonts

I am using the template here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/newspaper-slash-news-letter-template/wjxxhkxdjxhw

However, in the title, I want to put "XI" but it looks very different than an X and an I.

I want it to say XI Newspaper. Using this command
 `\SetPaperName{\Large XI Newspaper}` I get: 
[image]

If I change it to:

```
\SetPaperName{\Large XI News:\/paper}
```

I can get the s in newspaper to look better:

[image]

How do I get the XI (first two letters) to look more readable?

Comment: Don't link to external resources,  links can change over time,  add a small complete example to your question.  But beside this:  if you don't like the look  of the font you probably will have to use another one.

Answer (score 5):

They *do* look an X and an I in the Gothic font used by the `newspaper` document class.

You may want to use a different blackletter font, but none is really available in Type1 format.

If you're willing to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and have an up-to-date TeX distribution, you can use an English blackletter font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\newfontface{\mytitlefont}{QTCloisteredMonk.otf}[Scale=4]
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\@papername}{{\fontencoding{TU}\mytitlefont\@papername}}{}{}
\makeatother

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
%\SetPaperName{Committee Times:}
\SetPaperName{\Large XI Newspaper}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{Committee Times}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{Washington DC}
\SetPaperSlogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\SetPaperPrice{Zero Dollars}


% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}


%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
%\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\byline{Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}

The package is basically a redefinition of the \verb+\maketitle+ command.  The model was the New York Times---hopefully I haven't violated any copyright laws.  I also had to redefine the plain pagestyle.  It kept me busy for a few nights after work.  The rest is packages other people have written.      

\begin{window}[2,r,\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{example-image-1x1},\centerline{The Atom}] The \verb+multicol+ package allows using multiple columns without starting a new page.  Using floats is not possible in a columns environment, however with the \verb+picinpar+ package, I can set a picture inside a block of text---just like you one you see here.  Isn't \LaTeX{} cool?
And now we're just filling more space, and yet more space.  
\end{window}
\closearticle


\headline{Another Headline}
This is just an example to fill up some space, but as long as I have your attention, I'll give some newspaper advice.

I suppose we could also show how an equation is type set:
\begin{displaymath}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{displaymath}
and there you have it.  

\lipsum[1-4]

\closearticle

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

(I removed the call to `newspaper-mod.sty` that's incompatible).

[image]

Comment: Tried to compile in XeLaTeX in Texmaker but it says the font cannot be found